# Decomposition of matrix into sum of product of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

If I have an $n \times n$ matrix $X$ that is symmetric and positive semi-definite, how do I prove that there exists vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ such that

$$X = \sum_{i=1}^nv_iv_i^T$$

I know this is some form of factorization and know of how to find the eigenvectors of a matrix but am a little stuck on how to approach this. Any hints would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $V$ is symmetric and positive definite, there exists an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, \ldots e_n\}$ such that $Ve_i = \lambda_ie_i$ for some $\lambda_i > 0$.

Denote $P_i$ the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{span}\{e_i\}$, i.e. $P_ix = \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i$.

Note that we have the equality
$$V = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iP_i$$

Now verify that the matrix of $P_i$ w.r.t. the standard basis is $e_ie_i^T$. Hence
$$V = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_ie_ie_i^T = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sqrt{\lambda_i}e_i\right)\left(\sqrt{\lambda_i}e_i\right)^T$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense

Comment: Hi, sorry one question. Are the radicals placed correctly in your last line? Like is one of the eigenvectors not square-rooted?

Comment: @Anthony It was a typo, thanks for noticing.

Comment: sorry one last question, $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection of what onto the span?

Comment: @Anthony $P_i$ is the linear map which sends a vector $x$ to its orthogonal projection onto the subspace $\operatorname{span}\{e_i\}$, which is equal to $\langle x, e_i\rangle e_i$. The matrix of $P_i$ is $e_ie_i^T$ because $$(e_ie_i^T)x = e_i(e_i^Tx) = e_i\langle x, e_i\rangle$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** The matrix being symmetric, there exists an orthonormal basis which consists of eigenvectors of the matrix (see Spectral theorem).